# simple method postcondition might not hold

Tags: methods, dafny

I'm having problems with this simple method in Dafny and I don't know why it doesn't work. Since there are no debugger and I'm new to this language I hope somebody can help. I think the specification is incomplete..

```
method Q2(x : int, y : int) returns (big : int, small : int) 
  ensures big > small;
{
  if (x > y)
    {big, small := x, y;}
  else
    {big, small := y, x;}
}
```

When I run it in the microsoft dafny compiler I get the following:

A postcondition might not hold on this return path. (Line 8)
This is the postcondition that might not hold. (Line 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `x` and `y` might be equal, in which case, `big` and `small` will also be equal.

You can fix the postcondition by changing it to `big >= small`. Or, you want to forbid the caller from ever passing equal `x` and `y`, you could add a precondition requiring that `x != y`.